# sql query to get highest results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have asked a similar question before but since I did not get a response I was hoping to simply it a little better.

I have a table of records that containing google type results for example for a certain term there are specific number of records. I want a query that will select the terms for a given day with number of results per term in decreasing order.

Example Table

```
term      dateadded    resulturl
marines   2011-05-19   http:.../
```

Comment: insufficient detail, or possibly not given someone answered!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT term, COUNT(*) AS TermCount
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE dateadded = @YourDate
    GROUP BY term
    ORDER BY TermCount DESC
```

Comment: It was my understanding that, in T-SQL, you can't ORDER BY an alias created in the SELECT statement?  Requiring `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC` instead?

Comment: @Dems: No, the alias is acceptable in the `ORDER BY`. There are other places, such as `GROUP BY` or `HAVING`, where it cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select term
  , Count(*) as Result_Count
from TableName
where dateadded = @GivenDay -- don't know if time is a factor
group by term
order by result_count desc
```